# jQuery Post variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[Example of console results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtqkT.jpg)

Hi I have a problem with my jQuery I have a textbox that I want to make a live search from the database without submit button, Activates when i run showcharges($_GET["id"], $sort, $search) function that has already a select SQL query.
The problem with the ajax is that I want if search something to pass the data that i searched life on a php variable like $search as _POST['search']; on the same page.. to pass that data on my $search parameter of my function plus all of these without lose my query string of specific customer id in case of photo that is id=63 and is the first parameter of my function $_GET["id"]
so i want the ajax to keep my $_get["id"] and also to export to an _post['search'] variable the words that i searched.

I can't make it work.. they don't recognize the `_POST['search']`as a POST so the `$search;` is `unedified`

My PHP charge.php that calling the function Data::showcharges($_GET["id"], $sort, $search);

1. `$_GET["id"]` is query string from previous page that shows specific customer id on my query (working).
2. $sort is sorting the charges (enables only if is not null, inside function)
3. $search  searching query to find charges ,(enables only if is not null , inside function)

```php
<?php
    
if (isset($_POST['sort']))
{
 $sort = $_POST['sort'];
}
    
      
 $search = $_POST['search'];
 echo  $search; 
  
?>
    
     
    

$showcharge = Data::showcharges($_GET["id"], $sort, $search);          
        
<input type="text" name="search"  class="txt" />
    <span id="show" name="mytext"></span>
```

also, my sort form that sorting the charges (you can see the query inside the function that also want to replace with ajax life sorting and avoid the submit button and I don't want how can I do

```html
      <form action="" method="POST">
            <tr>
                <th> <select name="sort">
    
                        <option value="dateasc">Date Asc </option>
                        <option value="datedesc">Date Desc</option>
                        <option value="asc">Balance Asc </option>
                        <option value="desc">Balance Desc</option>
    
                    </select>
    
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Search</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </form>
```

My script that wants to replace the traditional submit button on the search box and make a life search without button

```html
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.txt').keyup(function() {
                var search = $(this).val();
                var val = "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>";
                $.ajax({
                    url: "charge.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: {
                        search: search,
                        val: val
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#show').html(search);
                        console.log(search);
                        console.log(val);

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My php function that is fully working. from dataprocess.php

```php
    
public static function showcharges($id = null, $sort = null, $search = null)
{    
    $sql = "SELECT id,contact_date,tasks,taskcharges,payment,balance,payment_date,admin,customers_id,comments,created_at";
    
    $sql .= " ,(select (taskcharges-payment) from customers where charges.customers_id=customers.id) as balance";
    
    $sql .= " FROM charges ";
    if (!empty($id)) {
        $sql .= " WHERE customers_id=" . $id;
    }
    
    if (!empty($search)) {  
    
        $sql .= "  AND tasks LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR comments LIKE  '%" . $search . "%'";
    }
    
    if ($sort == "asc") {   
            $sql .= "  ORDER BY balance ASC ";
        } elseif ($sort == "desc") {
    
        $sql .= " ORDER BY balance DESC ";
        } elseif ($sort == "dateasc") {    
        $sql .= " ORDER BY created_at ASC ";    
    } elseif ($sort == "datedesc") {
                $sql .= " ORDER BY created_at DESC ";
        }
        /* 
        echo $sql;
        die();  */
        $statement = conn()->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        $customers = $statement->fetchAll();
    
        return $customers;
}
```

Comment: Change `name="text"` => `name="query"` ... to get `query` in the `POST`. (or look for `text` in the `POST` instead)

Comment: @PaulT. Name of input not relevant to what is sent as `data` in the ajax config

Comment: Are you saying that when you do `$('#show').html(response);` you always see `0`  inserted in page?

Comment: What is the value of $_GET['id'] when you POST? Also show us the code of your Data::showcharges method

Comment: @Andreas I pasted the data from my function also i make more specific the code you can see the edited data Thank you

Comment: @charlietfl No  i make the the $('#show').html(response);  to test if the data passing to my html <span>  but i want to pass into a php variable as post on the same page, to take my function these parameter ($search) and select the spesific data

Comment: @PaulT. I tried my fiend and nothing happened, still doesn't recognize

Comment: your PHP parameter is named "$search" but you pass a parameter named `{ "query": search }` in your ajax data, it should be `{ search: search }`. and also your var "search" in javascript will return(s) not expected, possibly caused by a class. try to console.log(search ); what see what you get.

Comment: @JuliusLimson You are misinterpreting `$search = $_POST['query']`

Comment: At this point it is not really very clear what your specific problem is and what is working and what is not and steps you go through to run into errors

Comment: @JuliusLimson So i followed your instruction and seems to make one step further,
If you see i update the ajax code with two values , i can see the data only with datatype:"text"
Still doesn't recognize as $search = $_POST['search'], 
if you can see my site on photo i have one querystring id=63 that i want to keep and also the search value from search that i want export to php function as Data::showcharges($_GET["id"], $sort, $search); the $_GET['id'] want take the value from ajax val and the search from ajax search to run the query with the specific id.

Comment: @JuliusLimson If you can see the picture the only that i want is to keep the spesific query string of id  and to can export the ajax one value of $search = $_POST['search'] that is what i type on the keyboard on the input texbox to process the data on my php function.

Comment: @charlietfl Everything works on this: Data::showcharges($_GET["id"], $sort, $search);  
the problem is that i want to replace the $search with the life search textbox without submit and i dont know what im doing wrong , the $_GET['id'] is the id fo the specific customer that comes from the previous query string. that also want to keep one the new search that ill do you wan se the picture and the edited code of ajax

Comment: Suggest you rewrite the question so the specific problem is concise and easy to understand and includes all pertinent information , errors etc.

Comment: @charlietfl I rewrite the question i suppose to be more understandable sry due to multiple test  i messed up plus my English that is not very well..

Answer (score -2):

try this way

```
$.ajax({
   url: "charge.php",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: 'json'
   data: {
      query: search
   },
   success: function(response) {
   $('#show').html(response);
    
   }
```

});

when u send ajax via Jquery and want to set method of the request. u should use "type" and set data as JSON and after that u can use `$_POST` in php

Comment: Thanks for response,

Unfortunately they didn't work, even with datatype still get Undefined index: search look the code i cant see anything wrong :/ i spent 2 days to fix the problem without luck!

Look the code that i used above